# How to reply when someone says 'It means a lot'?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

In a scenario where you have encouraged someone but haven't helped them physically or with your time and they say "It means a lot". Just for the words you said. How should would one respond?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for the [Interpersonal Skills SE](http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @psosuna It's really not. It's outside of our scope. Please, if you're going to send people to other sites, particularly ones you don't use, at least encourage them to look at the site's help center to see if a question is on topic there.

Comment: @Catija I might not be understanding how it is off-topic when OP is asking the proper way to respond to a interpersonal situation, given that language is not the obstacle -- it's not a good fit for this SE either, but after looking through your help center and meta, I fail to understand just how it is off-topic. That all being said, your recommendation is a good one and I'll take it into account.

Comment: *Language* is an obstacle, actually... The OP is a language learner (admittedly, it was made clear in their question on IPS in a way that wasn't clear here). But we specifically prohibit phrasing requests. "What would you do" is also off topic along with being primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Catija It might be that there is some context absent here, but "How should/would one respond?" != "WWYD?", rather "How should/would one respond?" == "What is an appropriate response?". Again, this is absent the fact that here is not addressed that OP is a language learner (this happens after). At any rate, based on what I read on this specific post (and not being a user of IPS.SE thus unaware of where else this was already posted or not) I read this question as asking "What is an acceptable response to this situation?" and not "What words are a typical phrasing for X?" or a "WWYD?" question.

Answer (score 1):

I would respond the same way if someone had said "Thanks". The other person is expressing gratitude for your help, and I would respond accordingly. "You're welcome", "You bet", "Not a problem", "Anytime", etc.

Comment: "glad to help", "my pleasure" .. or other tacks that can add even more encouragement "I was there once myself - just passing on the help I got" etc.

Comment: Thank you @Tom22 & user64742. I am not a native speaker. But I think that "Anytime", "You are welcome" might be best in scenarios where you have done them some favor. But in the scenario where you have said just some words, how should you respond? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I was just adding other responses.  Understanding a full example would help.  If it were only encouragement, not help - and someone replied "I really appreciate it" it might be more appropriate to encourage them again with another "You can do it" or  "I'm rooting for you" or something like  rather than "anytime".  "Anytime" does works better if you might have done something a bit more than general encouragement - if you recommended they do something that is both help and encouragement.